# subtract a value from all the elements of matrix in openCV

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing

I have declared a matrix and then calculated the average of all the elements like this

```
        CvMat*  rgb1 = cvCreateMat(5, 5, CV_32FC1);
        // declared the elements of rgb1//
        CvScalar avg = cvAvg(rgb1); //calculated the average of all elements of rgb1 matrix
```

How can I subtract the average value (avg) from all the elements of rgb1 matrix which is a 2D 5*5 matrix as declared above. I am using openCV C API. Is there any function in openCV which can perform this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`cvSubS()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvSubS#subtract) to subtract a scalar value from each element of an image:

```
cvSubS(rgb1, avg, rgb1);
```

Comment: your answer is correct but it is better to use a new matrix of same type and size as destination matrix to avoid confusion

Comment: Any equivalent function in OpenCV 3?

Comment: @mhaghighat The C API is deprecated in OpenCV 3, so you must use the C++ version `cv::Mat`. This class supports the `-` operator, so you can just do `cv::Mat newMatrix = oldMatrix - 5;`